# Pycharm - Vagrant interpreter

Tags: vagrant, pycharm, interpreter

Hi I am trying to use PyCharm to debug a project using the interpreter on my vagrant machine. It worked perfectly before but has now stopped.

My settings are attached and the error message are in the screenshot below.

Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeRlR.png)

Answer (score 0):

The next thing i tried after posting this question was to delete the .idea folder from the project's folder and that fixed my problem.

My apologies if this was a stupid question but hopefully it helps someone else.